# Some questions about rigorous proof of cut and paste technique in constructing connected sum

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology, quotient-spaces, classifying-spaces

[Massey, p.11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St2qE.jpg)

I'm struggling with the above picture. *(Since I have not enough reputation, I would like you to click the link above)* The picture describes the steps of connecting two tori using the cut-and-paste technique. The problem is that, I can draw them in my mind vividly but I have no idea about how to show (a) and (b) are homeomorphic rigorously using explicit continuous function.

Need some help. Thank you.

- The black shaded part is an interior of a disk (up to homeomorphism) cut out of the torus.

Comment: Since after identification, all those vertices of the 2nd picture will identify to  a single point, so 1st picture is nothing but one step remodification of 2nd picture by identifying two vertices together along the edge $c_i$. Is that helpful for you?

Comment: The general tools you need are quotient maps and the pasting lemma. Do you know those?